# Javascript shorten string and find sentence end

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to shorted long string by number of characters (approximately) and finding sentence end (dot). Obviously this is not going to be 100% correct in all cases but its good enough. So for example, shorted string to 250 characters and find nearest dot as sentence end.

So having this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna. Donec consequat hendrerit magna. In iaculis neque eget nisi. Maecenas vehicula, leo eu commodo aliquam, sem dolor iaculis eros, vel mollis sem urna ac sapien. Integer mattis dui ut erat. Phasellus nibh magna, tempor vitae, dictum sed, vehicula sed, mauris. In enim arcu, porta vel, dictum eu, pretium a, ipsum. Donec cursus, lorem ac posuere viverra, sem tellus accumsan dolor, vel accumsan tortor est et est.
```

Would create this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna. Donec consequat hendrerit magna. In iaculis neque eget nisi. Maecenas vehicula, leo eu commodo aliquam, sem dolor iaculis eros, vel mollis sem urna ac sapien.
```

Things to consider I think:

If there is no dot in the string, shorten string by word boundary (so not to break a word) and add ellipsis (...) on the end which would be this function:

```
function truncateString( str, n, useWordBoundary ){
    if (str.length <= n) { return str; }
    var subString = str.substr(0, n-1);
    return (useWordBoundary 
       ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) 
       : subString) + "...";
};
```

How could one incorporate dot finding into this function?

Comment: What if the only dot appears at position 5? What if the only dot appears at position 1400?

Comment: What if there is a dot completely unrelated to the syntax of the sentence? `I live at 53 2nd St. Citysville in State; Would you be able to send the package there?`

Comment: `subString.lastIndexOf('.')` ??

Comment: After posting my proposed answer it dawned on me, what do you mean closest `.`? Does that mean make the string shorted or longer? I went with short but longer should be easy enough to implement.

Comment: @trincot - obviously logic should be closest to x (250), and a buffer of lets say 75. If there is no dot in that buffer, use ellipsis (...) . Thats my logic.

Comment: @Hodrobond - I mentioned its not going to be perfect in all scenarios but good enough. Maybe this could be improved to detect such cases?

Comment: @Adam H - I would use a buffer of lets say 75 to closes dot in any direction, and if no dot, then ellipsis (...)

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can make is splitting upp the string into chars in an array. Looping over the array from position 250 to position 0 and breaking when you find a dot. Take that index of the dot and splice the original array from the starting char, 0, to the dot which is the index value of that dot plus one as splice doesnt include the last value. Then turning that array into a string again.

```
let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna. Donec consequat hendrerit magna. In iaculis neque eget nisi. Maecenas vehicula, leo eu commodo aliquam, sem dolor iaculis eros, vel mollis sem urna ac sapien. Integer mattis dui ut erat. Phasellus nibh magna, tempor vitae, dictum sed, vehicula sed, mauris. In enim arcu, porta vel, dictum eu, pretium a, ipsum. Donec cursus, lorem ac posuere viverra, sem tellus accumsan dolor, vel accumsan tortor est et est.";

let arrarOfChar = string.split(""); //turns string into array
let position = -1; //-1 indicates that no dot has been found
for(let i = 250 ; i >= 0 ; i--) { //loop from 250 to 0
    if(arrarOfChar[i] == ".") { //if that char is equal to "."
    position = i; //set the position value to that
    break; //break the for loop
  }
}
if(position > 0) { //only if we found a dot
  let newShortArrayOfChar = arrarOfChar.slice(0,position+1); //shorten the array from 0 to the dot index
  let finalString = ""; //this is the final string
  for(let i = 0; i < newShortArrayOfChar.length ; i++) {
    finalString += newShortArrayOfChar[i]; //loop over every char and add it to the string
  }
}
else {
// position should be -1
//handle if no dot exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a regular expression: search for `n` or fewer characters, ending in a `.`, and if that match fails (there are no dots within the desired substring), search for `n` or fewer characters, followed by a word character and a word boundary:

```js
const input = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna. Donec consequat hendrerit magna. In iaculis neque eget nisi. Maecenas vehicula, leo eu commodo aliquam, sem dolor iaculis eros, vel mollis sem urna ac sapien. Integer mattis dui ut erat. Phasellus nibh magna, tempor vitae, dictum sed, vehicula sed, mauris. In enim arcu, porta vel, dictum eu, pretium a, ipsum. Donec cursus, lorem ac posuere viverra, sem tellus accumsan dolor, vel accumsan tortor est et est.`;

function truncateString( str, n, useWordBoundary ){
  const pattern = new RegExp(`^(?:.{1,${n}}\\.` + (
    useWordBoundary
    ? `|.{1,${n - 1}}\\w\\b)`
    : ')'
  ));
  const match = str.match(pattern);
  if (match) return match[0];
  else return 'Match failed';
}
console.log(truncateString(input, 70));
// first sentence is more than 50 characters long, so this fails:
console.log(truncateString(input, 50));
// unless you enable word boundaries:
console.log(truncateString(input, 50, true));
```

The regex pattern looks like:

```
^(?:.{1,50}\.|.{1,49}\w\b)
```

Breaking that down:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:` - Non-capturing group that alternates between:

  - `.{1,50}\.` - 50 or fewer characters, followed by a `.`, or:
  - `.{1,49}\w\b)` - 49 or fewer characters, followed by a word character and a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty straightforward example that trims the string to 250 characters then walks backward looking for the first . if it doesn't find one then the entire 250 characters are returned and if it does it trims it to that .

```js
var maxLength = 250;

function test() {
  var input = document.getElementById('test').value;
  var trimmed = input.substr(0, maxLength);

  var i = trimmed.length;
  while (i > 0) {
    if (trimmed[i] == '.') {
      break;
    }
    i--;
  }

  var endResult = i > 1 ? trimmed.substr(0, i + 1) : trimmed;
  endResult += endResult.length < input.length ? ' ...' : '';
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = endResult;
}
```

```css
.boxsizingBorder {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">
  test
</button>
<textarea id="test" class="boxsizingBorder" rows="5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna. Donec consequat hendrerit magna. In iaculis neque eget nisi. Maecenas vehicula, leo eu commodo aliquam, sem dolor iaculis eros, vel mollis sem urna ac sapien. Integer mattis dui ut erat. Phasellus nibh magna, tempor vitae, dictum sed, vehicula sed, mauris. In enim arcu, porta vel, dictum eu, pretium a, ipsum. Donec cursus, lorem ac posuere viverra, sem tellus accumsan dolor, vel accumsan tortor est et est.</textarea>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Yes I know I could have used .LastIndexOf .... i just wanted to get fancy with my backwards loop *drops mic*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add two more parameters to your function in order to express what the extreme limits are for the offset at which the string would be clipped.

So for instance, if *n* is 250, you could provide 200 as a minimum and maybe 270 as the ultimate maximum for the cut-off point.

Then here is how I would include the dot-break possibility:

```js
function truncateString( str, min, n, max, useWordBoundary ){
    if (str.length <= max) return str;
    if (useWordBoundary) {
        // Prefer to break after a dot:
        var i = str.indexOf(".", n)+1; // Look forward
        if (i < min || i > max) i = str.slice(0, n).lastIndexOf(".")+1; // ...or backward
        if (i >= min) return str.slice(0, i); // No ellipsis necessary
        // If dot-break is impossible, try word break: 
        i = str.indexOf(" ", n); // Look forward
        if (i < min || i > max) i = str.slice(0, n).lastIndexOf(" "); // ...backward
        if (i >= min) n = i; // Found an acceptable position
    }
    return str.substr(0, n) + " ...";
}

// Example:
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna. Donec consequat hendrerit magna. In iaculis neque eget nisi. Maecenas vehicula, leo eu commodo aliquam, sem dolor iaculis eros, vel mollis sem urna ac sapien. Integer mattis dui ut erat. Phasellus nibh magna, tempor vitae, dictum sed, vehicula sed, mauris. In enim arcu, porta vel, dictum eu, pretium a, ipsum. Donec cursus, lorem ac posuere viverra, sem tellus accumsan dolor, vel accumsan tortor est et est.";

console.log(truncateString(str, 200, 250, 270, true));
console.log(truncateString(str, 200, 250, 255, true));
```